# Convergence of sequence in $\Bbb{R}^{n}$ in dot product

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Let $\{\textbf{u}_{k}\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that converges to the point $\textbf{u}$, Prove that $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \langle{\textbf{u}_k,\textbf{v}} \rangle = \langle \textbf{u,v} \rangle$$

for every point $\textbf{v}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

attempt let $p_i(\textbf{u})=u_i$ be the $i$th coordinate of $\textbf{u}$. Since the sequence converges componentwise

$\lim_{k \to \infty} (p_1(\textbf{u}_k)v_1+\dots+p_n(\textbf{u}_k)v_n)=p_1(\textbf{u})v_1+\dots+p_n(\textbf{u})v_n=\langle \textbf{u},\textbf{v} \rangle$

Would this be the correct way to show this result?

Answer (score 2):

That's certainly one way. Another way would be to use Cauchy-Schwarz

$$ |\langle \mathbf u_k , \mathbf v\rangle - \langle \mathbf u , \mathbf v\rangle | =|\langle \mathbf u_k -\mathbf u,\mathbf  v\rangle|\le \| \mathbf u_k -\mathbf u \|\|\mathbf v\| \to 0.$$

Comment: how do you arrive at that first equality?

Comment: Linearity of inner products.

Comment: @ScottFrazier the dot product is linear in each input